# Laravel 8.0 Installation Failed

Tags: php, composer-php

[Click Here to View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaSPV.png)

I try to install laravel 8.0 on my local server PHP 8.0,Composer 2.6, but give this error pls help me

Message Show

**[InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 8.0 in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extens   ions and Composer version.**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `--ignore-platform-reqs` when you are installing a lower version of laravel.

full code: `composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 example --ignore-platform-reqs`
then change the php version on your composer.json from 7.3 to 8.0

Hope this solve your installation problem.

Another fix would be to install the last specific version of laravel 8:
`composer create-project laravel/laravel:8.6.11 example-boilerplate --prefer-dist`

Comment: Glad it helped. the last part of fix who be much recommended as it only needs the laravel version unlike the first fix that still requires configuration of php version.